# jQuery - Mouse enter flickers image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to do a simple hover over div and show/hide image.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s2WWM/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`

http://jsfiddle.net/s2WWM/2/

Also bind it on the container element.

The difference between these events is that `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` only count when you fully leave an element while `mouseover` and `mouseout` count when you leave the element regardless if you are still inside the element.

For example, when you leave an outer element for an inner element, that's a `mouseout` but not a `mouseleave` because you are still inside the outer element.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Learn something new everyday. :-)

Comment: @weka I added some explanations now, hope it helps. You pretty much always want `mouseenter/mouseleave` which are similar to CSS `:hover`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, when you hover over .fullscreen, you are no longer hovering over #canvas, so change it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#canvas, .fullscreen").mouseover(function() {
        console.log("Show...");
    $(".fullscreen").show();
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(".fullscreen").hide();
  });

});​
```